# Getting a char out of NSarray in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, arrays

I am trying to get a char out of an NSArray by generating  a random number. Here is my code

```
@interface ClassName : NSObject


@property (nonatomic) char letter;


-(id) init;

-(char) changeLetter;

@end
```

Implementation File:

```
#import "ClassName.h"

@interface ClassName()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *alphabet;



@end


@implementation ClassName


-(id) init {
[self alphabet];

return self;

}


-(NSArray *) alphabet
{
if (!_alphabet) _alphabet =
    @[@'A', @'B',@'C', @'D',@'E', @'F',
      @'G', @'H',@'I', @'J',@'K', @'L',
      @'M', @'N',@'O', @'P',@'Q', @'R',
      @'S', @'T',@'U', @'V',@'W', @'X',
      @'Y', @'Z'];




 return _alphabet;
}


-(char) changeLetter
{
//Picks a number between 0-26
int nextLetter = arc4random_uniform(26);

//Changes the value of the bubble
[self setValue: nextLetter];


return [self.alphabet objectAtIndex:nextLetter];
}



@end
```

The problem I am running into is the return statement coming from the changeLetter. It is telling me "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'id' from a function with result type 'char'

I have no idea what the problem is. I am new to Objective-C and am already getting very frustrated it already. It seems so hard and complicated compared to Java.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A `char` is a plain old data type, but `NSArray` holds Objective-C objects. It will return a pointer to an `NSString`, not a character.

Comment: Plus, I would suggest returning an NSString and not a char, unless you have need for the C level type.

Comment: @LyndseyScott - `@'A'` etc. are not strings, they are wrapped char values (instances of `NSNumber`) just what the OP intended.

Answer (score 2):

Coming from Java you might be confused as Java supports *autoboxing* and *autounboxing*.

In both Java & Objective-C you cannot store non-object types, such as integers and characters, directly in collections, such as arrays. Instead such values are stored as objects which *wrap* (or *box*) the basic value.

In Objective-C the common wrapper is `NSNumber` which is capable of storing integers, floating point numbers, characters and booleans. There is also an `NSValue` wrapper for storing other basic values.

Java will wrap a basic value as an object, and unwrap an object to produce the basic value, according to the context automatically. In Objective-C you must do this yourself.

Your expression: `@'A'` *et al* takes the character literal, `'A'`, and wraps it as an `NSNumber`. In Java the equivalent of the `@` would be inserted automatically.

So your array `_alphabet` contains instances of `NSNumber`. When you access an element of the array using:

```
[self.alphabet objectAtIndex:nextLetter]
```

the `NSNumber` instance in the array is returned, you still need to unwrap it to obtain the character and you do this with the `charValue` method:

```
[[self.alphabet objectAtIndex:nextLetter] charValue];
```

Again Java does the equivalent automatically for you.

*Note: for the actual task you are doing there are better ways to return a random capital letter, in your code you could even just use `'A' + nextLetter` (remember in C characters are just integers...).*

HTH